# Can $y''=1/y$ be solved without numerical way?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there  any way to solve it without numerical way??

$$ \frac{d^2 y}{d x^2}= \frac{1}{y}$$
thanks in advance!!

Comment: Analytical Solution does exist : http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%3D1%2Fy

Comment: Why don't you multiply by $y'$ in both sides and integrate? $$\mbox{Hint:}\quad y' y'' = \frac{1}{2} \big(y'^2\big)'$$

Comment: Got something from an answer below?

Answer (score 5):

Note that $y''y'=y'/y$ hence $(y')^2=c+2\log|y|$ hence $y'=\pm\sqrt{c+2\log|y|}$ and
$$
\int_{y(0)}^{y(x)}\frac{\mathrm dt}{\sqrt{c+2\log|t|}}=\pm x.
$$
The LHS does not seem to be (the inverse of) a usual function of $y(0)$ and $y(x)$. An equivalent formulation is
$$
\mathrm e^{-c/2}\int_{\sqrt{c+2\log|y(0)|}}^{\sqrt{c+2\log|y(x)|}}\mathrm e^{t^2/2}\mathrm dt=\pm x,
$$
and the LHS can be rewritten using the [imaginary error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) $\mathrm{erfi}$, with no obvious gain.

Comment: $x$ can be written in terms of $y$ using an erf function.

Comment: Tricky way (+1)

Comment: @BabakSorouh Classic trick in physics. Used in energy conserved systems. When a particle is under the action of a potential $V(x)$, where $x = x(t)$ is the position, the force is $f(x) = - \frac{d V}{d x}$, and the [equations of motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion) are $$m \ddot{x} = - \frac{d V}{dx}.$$ Multiplying by $\dot{x}$ both sides and integrating, one obtains $$E = \frac{1}{2} m \dot{x}^2 + V(x).$$ The first term is the [Kinetic Energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_energy) and the second the [Potential Energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_energy).

Comment: @BabakSorouh Thanks.