# what is the solution for this EDO y'y'' = 1

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I´ll appreciate any help with this EDO y'y''=1,

In some posts on internet theres a trick: multiply on each side y' and integrate but im not capable of doing that

Thanks, sorry if my english is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Suppose you define $z=y'$,so $z'=y''$ and the differential equation becomes $z z'=1$ or, write it better $$z \frac{dz}{dx}=1$$ which is separable $$z dz= dx$$ So $$ \frac{1}{2}z^2= x+c_1$$ $$z=\pm \sqrt{c_1+2 x}$$ So, since $z=y'$ one more integration step $$y=\pm\frac{1}{3} \left(c_1+2 x\right){}^{3/2}+c_2$$

You could do the same for the solution of $y' y''=a$ and you should then arrive to $$y=\pm\frac{2 \sqrt{2} \left(a x+c_1\right){}^{3/2}}{3 a}+c_2$$

Comment: Thank you so much, finally 6 hours ago i understood the sustitution and i did just what u did here, thanks.

Comment: You are very welcome. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can solve $vv'=1$ instead, then solve $y'=v$?

To solve $vv'=1$, notice the left-hand side is the derivative of what function of $v$?

Comment: well, i did not think in this sustitution, but, still, i dont have any initial values and i dont now how to derivate the new function v, plus i have found this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217005/can-y-1-y-be-solved-without-numerical-way
I was trying to understand the process but i cant.

Comment: @Dade In that post the ***purpose*** of multiplying by $y'$ was so that both sides would wind up being the derivative of some function of $y$. We don't even need to do anything to the equation $vv'=1$ to achieve that in your problem - the left-hand side is *already* the derivative of a function of $v$. If $[f(v)]'=vv'$, what is $f$? Use the chain rule!

Comment: Ty, with your approach and the next post i got the solution, thanks a lot